# Save Jupyter notebook before nbconvert

Tags: command-line, jupyter-notebook, save

I want to export a jupyter notebook within the notebook itself and use this command:

```
!jupyter nbconvert --to html MyNotebook.ipynb --output MyNotebook.html
```

This works correct, except that I manually need to save the notebook first for the latest outputs to be in the final html copy. Is there a similar command to save the notebook first (like hitting the save button) before doing the nbconvert?

Answer (score 1):

```
import IPython

%%javascript
IPython.notebook.save_notebook()
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.